# How to check if the input string from Scanner Util matches an initial string

Tags: java, string, boolean, java.util.scanner

So currently I have a setup where users enter a number from scanner util and I have a boolean that checks if the string entered is 4 digits and is only digits how can I create a boolean that would check it compared to another string for instance:

```
String pin = "6357";
```

what type of boolean would I have to compare the string to the one entered by user. Here is my current code checking the length go the string:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pin
{

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner( System.in );
    String      pin;
    System.out.print( "Enter pin: " );
    pin = kbd.next();
    System.out.println( "Valid: " + isValid(pin) );
    System.out.println( "Is int: " + isInt(pin) );
    System.out.println( "MD5: " + md5HexString(pin) );
}

public static boolean isInt( String s ) {
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt( s );
        System.out.println( "Int: " + i );
        return true;
    }
    catch( Exception ex ) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean isValid( String s ) {
    return s.matches( "\\d{4}" ); // must be 4 digits long
}
```

As can be seen this does not compare it to another existing string so what if I had something like this:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pin
{
   String pinnum = "6357";

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner( System.in );
    String      pin;
    System.out.print( "Enter pin: " );
    pin = kbd.next();
    System.out.println( "Valid: " + isValid(pin) );
    System.out.println( "Is int: " + isInt(pin) );
    System.out.println( "MD5: " + md5HexString(pin) );
}

public static boolean isInt( String s ) {
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt( s );
        System.out.println( "Int: " + i );
        return true;
    }
    catch( Exception ex ) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean isValid( String s ) {
    //what to put here?
}
```

In this example I pre set up a pin that I would like to check if what the user entered through scanner util matches exactly. Is this possible?

Comment: Just note `isInt` is not necessary you can just use `isValid` to check if the input is a valid integer or not

Comment: *//what to put here?* you can use `return pin.equals(s):`

Comment: Note also that the sharp in the end of `ping#` illegal character in java!

Comment: In the second piece of code you also don't need to check `isInt`!

Comment: @YCF_L ahh yes thanks for pointing that out I just changed it and I did not think through the ending of #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the `.equals()` method to comapare two values to see if they match.

```
pinnum.equals(s)
```

a more detailed explanation can be found here: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: i just left it there to show that its the user entered pin and not the hardcoded pin - but yeah you are right - shouldn't use those characters!

Comment: Thanks for the code and thanks for whoever left the link too will check that out for more since I will be expanding more later!

Answer (score 1):

If you are really working on validations, for the sake of Single Responsibility ([SOLID Principles](https://www.google.com/search?q=SOLID%20Principles)) it is better to have this kinds of validation things in another class. In this case you can use .equals() method.